# Firebase with special character ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase

I have a need sent a message

```
message = "welcome to Andrew's Bar"
params_json = {registration_ids: ids, notification: {title: "Welcome",text: message, icon:"myicon"},data: data}.to_json
system("curl -X POST --header 'Authorization: key=#{ENV['API_KEY']}' --Header 'Content-Type: application/json' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '#{params_json}'")
```

the error message:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

causate by " ' " in  Andrew's

How to send a string with special characters for Firebase post on Ruby On Rails?

Comment: You could scape the quote: `message = "welcome to Andrew\'s Bar"`

Comment: Thanks but dont work